# Excel Default Normal Font was a mess (between my Office and Home Pc)

Tags: excel, fonts, excel-2010

In my Office PC, I have Cambria (Heading) and Calibri (Body) if you click on the Font Dropdown.

[image]

And, when I open the file in my home pc, even though the font is set to Calibri 11, it changes to Tahoma 11 in my home.

That is... Tahoma is Headings and Tahoma is Body (in Theme Fonts section) in my Home PC.

This causes problems in viewing Excel files in my home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By going to Language Preferences...

http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_global_experience/archive/2010/03/18/my-language-preferences-office-editing-languages.aspx

In my office PC, there was only English Language.

But in my home pc, there is english and Thai... and Thai was set as default..

After I change the default to English... everything is now back to normal.

No more Tahoma 11 issue in my home pc.. behaviour is same as my office pc.

[image]